# Проблема с layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

Ребята,хотел сделать побольше высоту nav_header,ибо картинка слишком маленькая получается.
Но когда я изменил высоту,у меня поехали остальные xml файлы.

Вот здесь я хотел изменить высоту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После изменения высоты шторка выглядит так как надо,но остальные xml посдвигались непонятно как.

Должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возвращал все значения в исходные, чтобы уже было как раньше,фиг с той высотой,но даже поставив исходную высоту ничего не меняется.
Что нужно изменить?

activity_main.xml

```
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        app:siBorderColor="@color/tw__solid_white"
        app:siBorderWidth="6dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_nick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

xml profile

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Profile">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="242dp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_name"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_email"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.09"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/profile_phone"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: В первую очередь нужно приложить код разметки

Comment: @zTrap добавил в вопрос